# Update only non-zero weights in a Tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor, backpropagation

Is there a way to efficiently update (retrain) only the non-zero weights in a TF model?
The idea here is to reduce the retraining time and therefore, I'm trying to find a way to calculate gradients only for the non-zero weights. This is the training function

```
 @tf.function
 def train_step(inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
       predictions = model(inputs, training=True)
       loss_value = loss_fn(targets, predictions)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
    return loss_value
```

Highly appreciate any advice on this as I couldn't find any way to do this

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the model you use? I guess you have layers with mixed zero and non-zero weights, otherwise whole layers can be set to `trainable=False`, but I guess you already know that.

Comment: @Blindschleiche Thank you very much for your comment. Yes, i have layers with mixed zero and non-zero weights. I have pruned the model up to 80% (the majority of weights are zero). i can't use ```trainable=False``` as i don't want to freeze specific layers. My model includes embedding(10), GRU (16) and a classification layer (85)

Comment: I checked some projects, which I know people used some sparse variables, as you described them.  But they did not care about an efficient update of the weights.  I also checked the tf.sparse operations and LazyAdam, but I did not find anything particular useful.  Unfortunately, I think I cannot provide real advise, but I wish you best luck for your problem.

Comment: @Blindschleiche Yes, it seems really challenging. If i find a solution, I'll post it here. Thank you very much for your effort!